# What good book questions have been asked and answered on SO before?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, books

Are there already good questions and answers about books?
Or should I ask yet another question about the best programming book?

Comment: I really don't mind any up or downvotes on this. I just want a list of book questions which I can link. Telling ppl to use search doesn't help.

Comment: Oh nice, Rich B has found a place where he can freely be rude to ppl and make snide comments.

Comment: @tharkun: That is called 'The Internet'.

Comment: for you maybe, yes, sadly!

Comment: We've had our own channel for months.  Come to #somafia on irc.slashnet.org and Rich can hate you on a much more personal level.

Comment: This really serves no purpose. There are search and tag functions for a reason.

Comment: @btk: I really don't think I would tolerate someone talking in txt msg speech for very long.

Comment: :) I know, yes, I do know that.

Answer (score 11):

Most probably you shouldn't ask another question. There are a zillion questions and answers on SO about books. The tag 'books' has been used over 777 times so far.

#### Very popular

- [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)
- [What development book made the most impact on you as a developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406/what-development-book-made-the-most-impact-on-you-as-a-developer)
- [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873/language-books-tutorials-for-popular-languages)

#### Also popular

- [“Must Have” Books on Your Bookshelf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170208/must-have-books-on-your-bookshelf)
- [What Programming Book would you NOT recommend to Developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184118/what-programming-book-would-you-not-recommend-to-developers)
- [What was your first programming book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832941/what-was-your-first-programming-book)
- [Which book dramatically changed your way of approaching problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305691/which-book-dramatically-changed-your-way-of-approaching-problems)

#### Beginner programmers

- [What books would you recommend for a beginning Software Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559/what-books-would-you-recommend-for-a-beginning-software-developer)

#### Advanced programmers

- [Books for advanced programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393455/books-for-advanced-programmers)

#### Topics

- Design Patterns: [What are the best design patterns books you have read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105049/what-are-the-best-design-patterns-books-you-have-read)
- PHP: [What is the best PHP programming book?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book)
- Rails: [Rails books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83784/rails-books)

#### Free programming books

- [What are some good free programming books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391523/what-are-some-good-free-programming-books)
- [List of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

#### Meta discussion about programming books

- [Should you always read a book when picking up a new technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506501/should-you-always-read-a-book-when-picking-up-a-new-technology)
- [Do programmers read books? Or is the book industry dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347821/do-programmers-read-books-or-is-the-book-industry-dead)
- [Are programming books a necessity nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165473/are-programming-books-a-necessity-nowadays)
- [How can I convince my boss to buy books for programmers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233903/how-can-i-convince-my-boss-to-buy-books-for-programmers)
- [When to Throw Out Old Programming Books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208293/when-to-throw-out-old-programming-books)
- [How Do You Read Books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419042/how-do-you-read-books)
- [What makes a good technical book ‘good’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101084/what-makes-a-good-technical-book-good)

#### Other books for programmers

- [Best programming novel to take on holiday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133556/best-programming-novel-to-take-on-holiday)
- [What non-programming books should programmers read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read)
- [Best non-development book for software developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274/best-non-development-book-for-software-developers)

Comment: And you didn't even make the answer CW. Wow. Just wow.

Comment: Thanks for collecting these links. I think the downvoters have been a little unfair to you. However, if you do want to add this to the FAQ, one of the requisite steps is to mark the question and answer as Community Wiki so other people can edit them.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a good FAQ topic at all. Users should search the questions for "books" and see if their question matches, they shouldn't have to check a FAQ for listings of questions that have already been asked, lest we end up with dozens of FAQ pages that keep a list of all the questions already asked for certain topics.

**Edit**: Making another post to highlight to people that there are dupes is completely nonsensical. So instead of posting to relevant dupes you want to post to a post about relevant dupes. Congratulations you just added another layer to the whole mess instead of saying "This is a dupe" and you close it as such, which would then point back to the correct question(s).

**[facepalm]**

Comment: Agreed! People need to just put more (some) effort into searching first. I doubt they ever do, considering how often things are duplicated.

Comment: I just don't want to list 10 book questions everytime someone writes a dupe. I want to have a nice list to show ppl quickly that there are actually really a lot of good book questions. And Meta is exactly the place for such a list. Whether it is a FAQ question or not, I don't care.

Comment: @facepalm: in your opinion it's nonsensical. in mine it isn't.

Comment: books are a meta-topic. it's not like I'm going to do this for every tag on SO.

Comment: +1. This is ridiculously off topic. The fact that it was posted on SO.com first is just astounding.

Comment: of course +1 :) the infallibles have always voted each other up :D

Comment: @Tharkun: Well if you weren't so wrong all the time, our constant correctness wouldn't make us look infallible.